# Specify a menu in a answer

Tags: discussion

If I answer somebody saying him that he must go to the wheel menu that is on the top-right corner of the screen, how can I do? before now I used a extended description as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut it out from a screenshot and add that one to your answer.

Comment: There isn't a better method?

Comment: What do you expect? Either you know the specific name of a menu (but maybe the questioner does not know it!), you describe where/how to find it with words or you show him a picture of the menu. I don't really see other options, do you?

Comment: Ok, thank you, if in a hour nobody gives me a best answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I don't really care, as meta gives no reputation points, but please do so to mark it as "solved".

Comment: Ok, thanks for all!

Comment: I believe the official name is "power cog" but hardly anyone knows that so a  screen shot would also be useful in most cases.